# Make CSS background image scroll

Tags: html, css, scroll, background-image

How do I make this background image scroll with the rest of the page?  (Background-attachment: scroll; does not work.)  Before scrolling,  I have the background image and the logo positioned where I want them to stay, but when it scrolls, the logo and title scroll but the navbar and background image do not.

```
.content {
    overflow: auto;
    position: relative;
    }
.content:before {
    content: "";
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top:-175px;
    z-index: -1;

    display: block;
    background-image: url("/assets/backgroundpic.jpg");
    background-size:cover;
    background-position:center top;

    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
}



<div class="container content text-center" style="position:relative;">
  <%= image_tag("/assets/logo-seal.png", size: "250x250", class: "img-responsive img-circle margin", style: "display:inline;margin-top:200px;") %>
  <h1 style="font: 48px Oswald, sans-serif;">TITLE</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This background-image is assigned to an element that has `position: fixed;`. Since the element won't scroll (being fixed), it's background will neither.

You have to find a solution without fixing that element.

Comment: Thank you! I changed the position to absolute and put the content class in a div outside of the container.  I don't know how I didn't think of that before.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have problems using jQuery here is an easy way
https://bavotasan.com/2011/full-sizebackground-image-jquery-plugin/